# Matlab: regexp usage

Tags: matlab

I am going to start illustration using a code:

```
A = 'G1(General G1Airlines american G1Fungus )';
```

Using regexp (or any other function) in Matlab I want to distinctively locate: G1, G1A and G1F.

Currently if I try to do something as:

```
B = regexp( A, 'G1')
```

It is not able to distinguish G1 with the G1A and G1F i.e. I need to force the comparison to find me only case with G1 and ignore G1A and G1F.

However, when I am searching for G1A then it should still find me the location of G1A.

Can someone please help ?

Edit: Another case for A is:

```
A = 'R1George Service SmalR1Al C&I)';
```

And the expression this time I need to find is R1 and R1A instead.

Edit:
I have a giant array containing A's and another big vector containing G1, R1, etc I need to search for.

Comment: Your question is after getting confusing with the edit. I now don't find it clear what you want and am not sure my answer satisfies the question?

Comment: I tried to clarify, is it clearer ?

Comment: I think my answer should satisfy your needs. Am I right?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. In the second case, how do you distinguish the two occurrences of R1? What is the rule behind?

Comment: I am dealing with large of sub strings I need to search for. Since I don't know at what point I am going to get G1, G1A or G1F or R1 or any other substring, I find it hard to implement your solution. However, it does work if I have only G1, G1A and G1F to search for.

Comment: I just figured a non - efficient way to implement the solution below. But if something smart comes to deal with my situation please post. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find `'G1'` but not `'G1A'` or `'G1F'` you can use

```
>> B = regexp(A, 'G1[^AF]')
B =
     1
```

This will find `'G1'` and the `^` is used to specify that it should **not** match any characters contained with `[]`. Then you could use

```
>> B = regexp(A, 'G1[AF]')
B =
    12    32
```

to find both `'G1A'` and `'G1F'`.